# Why does this man page have today's date?

Tags: unattended-upgrades

Why would a specific `man` page (in my case, for the `nc` command) have today's date without me doing any updates to the system ? Also, why doesn't the "unattended update" log show any specific activity for that day?

```
2018-03-14 07:47:38,124 INFO Initial blacklisted packages:
2018-03-14 07:47:38,135 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2018-03-14 07:47:38,135 INFO Allowed origins are: ['o=LinuxMint,a=qiana-security', 'o=LinuxMintESM,a=qiana']
2018-03-14 07:47:51,767 INFO No packages found that can be upgraded unattended and no pending auto-removals
```

This is footer for the `nc` man page:

```
BSD                             March 14, 2018                             BSD
```

That's on Linux Mint 17 (qiana), based on Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty) with groff 1.22.2 and man-db 2.6.7.1.

**EDIT**

Requested commands outputs :

1. `man -aw nc`

   ```
   /usr/share/man/man1/nc_openbsd.1.gz
   ```
2. `ls -ld $(man -aw nc)`

   ```
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5.7K Dec  4  2012 /usr/share/man/man1/nc_openbsd.1.gz
   ```

Which is weird...

3. `dpkg -S $(man -aw nc)`?

   ```
   netcat-openbsd: /usr/share/man/man1/nc_openbsd.1.gz
   ```
4. `type -a man`

   ```
   man is /usr/bin/man
   ```
5. `zgrep docdate $(man -aw nc)`

   ```
   .Dd $Mdocdate: February 7 2012 $
   ```
6. **ADDED FOOTER** `strace -f man nc 2>&1 | grep -e '^BSD' -e '"/.*nc'`

   ```
   ychaouche#ychaouche-PC 14:31:15 ~ $ strace -f man nc 2>&1 | grep -e '^BSD' -e '"/.*nc'
   execve("/usr/bin/man", ["man", "nc"], [/* 87 vars */]) = 0
   lstat("/usr/share/man/man1/nc.1.gz", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0777, st_size=25, ...}) = 0
   lstat("/usr/share/man/man1/nc.1.gz", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0777, st_size=25, ...}) = 0
   readlink("/usr/share/man/man1/nc.1.gz", "/etc/alternatives/nc.1.gz", 4095) = 25
   lstat("/etc/alternatives/nc.1.gz", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0777, st_size=35, ...}) = 0
   readlink("/etc/alternatives/nc.1.gz", "/usr/share/man/man1/nc_openbsd.1"..., 4095) = 35
   lstat("/usr/share/man/man1/nc_openbsd.1.gz", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=5756, ...}) = 0
   stat("/usr/share/man/man1/nc_openbsd.1.gz", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=5756, ...}) = 0
   stat("/usr/share/man/man1/nc_openbsd.1.gz", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=5756, ...}) = 0
   open("/usr/share/man/man1/nc_openbsd.1.gz", O_RDONLY) = 3
   access("/usr/share/man/man1/nc.1.gz", R_OK) = 0
   lstat("/usr/share/man/man1/nc.1.gz", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0777, st_size=25, ...}) = 0
   lstat("/usr/share/man/man1/nc.1.gz", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0777, st_size=25, ...}) = 0
   readlink("/usr/share/man/man1/nc.1.gz", "/etc/alternatives/nc.1.gz", 4095) = 25
   lstat("/etc/alternatives/nc.1.gz", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0777, st_size=35, ...}) = 0
   readlink("/etc/alternatives/nc.1.gz", "/usr/share/man/man1/nc_openbsd.1"..., 4095) = 35
   lstat("/usr/share/man/man1/nc_openbsd.1.gz", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=5756, ...}) = 0
   stat("/usr/share/man/man1/nc_openbsd.1.gz", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=5756, ...}) = 0
   stat("/usr/share/man/man1/nc_openbsd.1.gz", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=5756, ...}) = 0
   open("/usr/share/man/man1/nc_openbsd.1.gz", O_RDONLY) = 3
   stat("/usr/share/man/man1/nc.1.gz", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=5756, ...}) = 0
   stat("/usr/share/man/cat1/nc.1.gz", 0x7fffa49c0940) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
   stat("/usr/share/man/man1/nc_openbsd.1.gz", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=5756, ...}) = 0
   open("/usr/share/man/man1/nc_openbsd.1.gz", O_RDONLY) = 3
   [pid  3878] stat("/usr/share/man/man1/nc_openbsd.1.gz", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=5756, ...}) = 0
   [pid  3878] access("/usr/share/man/man1/nc_openbsd.1.gz", R_OK <unfinished ...>
   BSD                             March 20, 2018                             BSD
   ```
7. `strace -f man nc 2>&1 | grep -vwe -1 | grep -o '"/[^"]*"' | sort -u | grep -v /dev/ | xargs sh -c 'zgrep "March 14" "$@"' sh 2> /dev/null`

   ```
    no output
   ```

   it seems the date isn't hardcoded. Could be a macro generating today's date.
8. `env | grep -e ROFF -e MAN -e GRO`

   ```
   SESSION_MANAGER=local/ychaouche-PC:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/2915,unix/ychaouche-PC:/tmp/.ICE-unix/2915
   MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/default.mandatory.path
   ```
9. `env -i man nc` shows today's date (March 20th 2018)
10. `zcat /usr/share/man/man1/nc_openbsd.1.gz | nroff -mandoc | grep BSD`

    ```
    ychaouche#ychaouche-PC 06:59:53 ~ $ zcat /usr/share/man/man1/nc_openbsd.1.gz | nroff -mandoc | grep BSD
    NC(1)                     BSD General Commands Manual                    NC(1)
    BSD                             March 20, 2018                             BSD
    ychaouche#ychaouche-PC 07:01:41 ~ $
    ```
11. `strace -f man nc 2>&1 | grep -vwe -1 | grep -o '"/[^"]*tmac/[^"]*"' | sort -u | xargs ls -lrtd`

    ```
    ychaouche#ychaouche-PC 17:26:08 /usr/share/man/man1 $ unalias ls
    ychaouche#ychaouche-PC 17:26:12 /usr/share/man/man1 $ unalias xargs
    ychaouche#ychaouche-PC 17:26:14 /usr/share/man/man1 $ unalias grep
    ychaouche#ychaouche-PC 17:26:16 /usr/share/man/man1 $ strace -f man nc 2>&1 | grep -vwe -1 | grep -o '"/[^"]*tmac/[^"]*"' | sort -u | xargs ls -lrtd
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4065 Jan 22  2014 /usr/share/groff/1.22.2/tmac/papersize.tmac
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1860 Jan 22  2014 /usr/share/groff/1.22.2/tmac/andoc.tmac
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    71 Jan 22  2014 /usr/share/groff/1.22.2/tmac/unicode.tmac
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1552 Jan 22  2014 /usr/share/groff/1.22.2/tmac/tty.tmac
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  5183 Jan 22  2014 /usr/share/groff/1.22.2/tmac/tty-char.tmac
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1145 Jan 22  2014 /usr/share/groff/1.22.2/tmac/troffrc-end
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1387 Jan 22  2014 /usr/share/groff/1.22.2/tmac/troffrc
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4729 Jan 22  2014 /usr/share/groff/1.22.2/tmac/pspic.tmac
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 22042 Jan 22  2014 /usr/share/groff/1.22.2/tmac/mdoc/doc-syms
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4048 Jan 22  2014 /usr/share/groff/1.22.2/tmac/mdoc/doc-nroff
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 29284 Jan 22  2014 /usr/share/groff/1.22.2/tmac/mdoc/doc-common
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2250 Jan 22  2014 /usr/share/groff/1.22.2/tmac/latin1.tmac
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 27860 Jan 22  2014 /usr/share/groff/1.22.2/tmac/hyphen.us
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 15678 Jan 22  2014 /usr/share/groff/1.22.2/tmac/hyphenex.us
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1362 Jan 22  2014 /usr/share/groff/1.22.2/tmac/fallbacks.tmac
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 73807 Jan 22  2014 /usr/share/groff/1.22.2/tmac/doc.tmac
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   537 Jan 22  2014 /usr/share/groff/1.22.2/tmac/composite.tmac
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   704 Jan 22  2014 /usr/share/groff/site-tmac/mdoc.local
    ychaouche#ychaouche-PC 17:26:18 /usr/share/man/man1 $
    ```

Comment: It was today yesterday. I updated the post description to include the requested commands output.

Comment: The manpage’s source code is visible [here](https://sources.debian.org/src/netcat-openbsd/1.105-7/nc.1/) (in the version apparently installed on the OP’s system).

Comment: Is ‘man’ aliased or overridden? `type -a man` output would help.

Comment: `man is /usr/bin/man`

Comment: @Stéphane see https://sources.debian.org/src/netcat-openbsd/1.105-7/nc.1/#L28

Comment: surprisingly, I get `.Dd $Mdocdate: February 7 2012 $`

Comment: How about `strace -f man nc 2>&1 | grep -e '^BSD' -e '"/.*nc'`

Comment: That's a lot of though on such a small problem :D

Comment: @Kiwy, well, that's an intriguing problem. And could be caused by a bigger problem.

Comment: And maybe `strace -f man nc 2>&1 | grep -vwe -1 | grep -o '"/[^"]*"' | sort -u | grep -v /dev/ | xargs sh -c 'zgrep "March 14" "$@"' sh 2> /dev/null` to try and see where that `March 14` comes from.

Comment: Do you get the same with `env -i man nc`? Do you have any roff or man-related variable in your environment? (`env | grep -e ROFF -e MAN -e GRO`)?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas true, I will try to decrypt what your asking for, those command could be usefull one day.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I edited the question with requested output

Comment: The `grep -e '^BSD'` doesn't show the footer line. Is it still showing `March 14`? Or today's `date` (`March 19`)? What about the `env -i`? Do you get the same footer if you call nroff directly (`zcat /usr/share/man/man1/nc_openbsd.1.gz | nroff -mandoc | grep BSD`)?

Comment: Maybe `strace -f man nc 2>&1 | grep -vwe -1 | grep -o '"/[^"]*tmac/[^"]*"' | sort -u | xargs ls -lrtd` to see if there have been recent modifications to some roff macros

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, I forgot to mention that it is showiong today's date on each day now. The first time I encoutered this problem it showed the same date on two consecutive dates (today on first day and yesterday on second day), maybe because I didn't reboot the system on that particular day ?

Comment: That you had to remove the quotes is also odd. Does `echo '"/"' | xargs ls -ld` not work? `xargs` is meant to recognise quotes (that part I cannot reproduce on Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: Ah it must be that my xargs is aliased to `xargs -0 --delimiter='\n'`

Comment: `-0` and `--delimiter='\n'` make little sense together (one sets the delimiter to NUL, the other to LF)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GNU roff used not to support those:

```
 .Dd $Mdocdate: February 7 2012 $
```

OpenBSD extension (here that `$Mdocdate: ...$` being a CVS/RCS keyword expanded by CVS (which OpenBSD uses to version control their code) with the date of the manual revision), resulting in the current date to be expanded instead of the one specified. I can reproduce it on Ubuntu 14.04 for all man pages that have such a `Mdocdate`.

See https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?42968 implemented in https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/groff-commit/2014-10/msg00092.html (groff version 1.22.3).

---

For man pages from MirBSD (now MirOS) like your `paxcpio` or `mksh`, which use the same `$Mdocdate: ...$` CVS keyword, you'll find the man pages redefine (wrap) the `.Dd` mdoc macro themselves, so the roff system macros don't have to support it:

> ```
> .\"
> .\" Implement .Dd with the Mdocdate RCS keyword
> .\"
> .rn Dd xD
> .de Dd
> .ie ^G\\$1^G$Mdocdate:^G \{\
> .       xD \\$2 \\$3, \\$4
> .\}
> .el .xD \\$1 \\$2 \\$3 \\$4 \\$5 \\$6 \\$7 \\$8
> ..
> .\"
> .\" .Dd must come before definition of .Mx, because when called
> .\" with -mandoc, it might implement .Mx itself, but we want to
> .\" use our own definition. And .Dd must come *first*, always.
> .\"
> .Dd $Mdocdate: August 16 2017 $
> ```

Comment: That was one brilliant debugging. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ychaouche, now looking backward, that should have been one of the few things to look at, but for some reason I thought your Mint Qiana was based on Ubuntu 16.04 instead of 14.04 and couldn't reproduce it on 16.04

Comment: Using zgrep as shown in your comment, I made a list of all the man pages that had this "bug" : https://gist.github.com/ychaouche/fabe43225d1692dc325826d2be521bc4. I manually verified some of them, the bug is there. But it seems to have been fixed in Debian 8 (using 8.10 on one of the servers, bug not there.)

Comment: `man ssh` shows the current date on a Debian 8.10 system here with groff 1.22.2-8. Maybe you get the `groff` package from  a newer release (stretch has 1.22.3). See `apt-cache policy groff`.

Comment: No I was mislead by `man paxcpio` ! debian 8.10 here too, confirming bug for `man ssh` and `man ssh-keygen` as well, but `man paxcpio` shows `MirBSD June 5, 2012 MirBSD`

Comment: Manually checked and confirmed for the following man pages : https://gist.github.com/ychaouche/f4201c5f68cb7b15ee2fa41f3cbe841c

Comment: @ychaouche, it's not really a bug, it's that OpenBSD added a new format for the `.Dd` mdoc macro  (which otherwise accepts `Month day, year`), so they could use CVS keyword in it (here `$Mdocdate: ... $` which is expanded by CVS to the date of the document revision). They updated their own `mdoc` macros for that  and those modifcations were later merged into groff so that OpenBSD man pages could be properly formatted on other systems.